# Best open approximations of the diagonal

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A$ is a topological space and $\Delta_A\subseteq |A|\times |A|$ is the diagonal relation. $\Delta_A$ is rarely open (indeed it is open if an only if the topology on $A$ is discrete), but it is always contained in an open set (trivially $|A|\times |A|$). So my question is: are there general conditions that allow to find the smallest open set that contains the diagonal (say being $T_0$, $T_1$, compact or whatever)?

I know that the smallest open set that contains a given set may not exist in general, but hopefully this is different for the specific case of the diagonal (maybe with the help of some separation axiom).

Comment: Look at the diagonal $\Delta \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$: there's no smallest open set containing it. And you can't really make a nicer space than $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: In, say, a manifold or cell-complex of dimension $\ge 1$, there is never a smallest open neighborhood of the diagonal.

Comment: Furthermore, there is an entire sub-branch of topology, namely the theory of "uniform spaces", where a neighborhood basis of the diagonal is the main added structure of the topology. The study of uniform spaces is the natural subcategory of topological spaces in which "uniform continuity" may be formulated.

Comment: Dear Najib and Lee, thank you for your reply and for the suggestion concerning uniform spaces.

Comment: I hope it is not too late, but I'm thinking at a refinement of my previous question: are there some nice conditions (some separation axiom or compactness) which guarantee the existence of the smallest open equivalence relation?